# Using positional replacement and conversion specifiers in this question?

Tags: python

This is the question:
A half-life is the amount of time it takes for a substance or entity to fall to half its original value. Caffeine has a half-life of about 6 hours in humans. Given caffeine amount (in mg) as input, output the caffeine level after 6, 12, and 24 hours. Use  a  string  formatting  expression  with  positional  replacement  and  conversion  specifiers  to output the count of hours as integer, caffeine amount as floating-point numbers with 1 digit after the decimal point.

This is my code:

```
mg = float(input('Please input the initial caffeine amount in mg: '))
mg /= 2
print('After 6 hours:','{:.1f}'.format(mg),'mg caffeine left')
mg /= 2
print('After 12 hours:','{:.1f}'.format(mg),'mg caffeine left')
mg /= 4
print('After 24 hours:','{:.1f}'.format(mg),'mg caffeine left')
```

Does my code use positional  replacement  and  conversion  specifiers? If not how could I incorporate those concepts in my code?

Thank you!

Comment: `{:.1f}` is (implicitly) a positional replacement. As the first (and only) replacement field in the string, it is equivalent to `{0:.1f}`, where the `0` before the `:` refers to the first positional argument passed to `format`.

Comment: I'm somewhat concerned that something was lost in translation, as "positional replacement" isn't a generally used python term. Do you have any examples of this from class materials?

Comment: @BeRT2me Not that exact phrase, but the `{...}`s are referred to as replacement fields, and numeric fields names refer to positional arguments in https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It does use both already however, I think it would be more obvious and more readable if you edited it like this:

```py
mg = float(input('Please input the initial caffeine amount in mg: '))
mg /= 2
print('After 6 hours: {:.1f} mg caffeine left'.format(mg))
mg /= 2
print('After 12 hours: {:.1f} mg caffeine left'.format(mg))
mg /= 4
print('After 24 hours: {:.1f} mg caffeine left'.format(mg))
```

or even better:

```py
mg = float(input('Please input the initial caffeine amount in mg: '))
for t,i in zip([6,12,24], [2, 4, 16]):
    print('After {:.0f} hours: {:.1f} mg caffeine left'.format(t, mg/i))
```

the `str.format` method returns a copy of the string where each `{...}` is replaced with the string value of the corresponding arguments.

For a more detailed explanation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm just learning python and the first code definetly looks cleaner. I'm wondering why the code still works even though I put (mg) at the end?

We haven't learned for loops yet but your code will help me understand it better! :)

Comment: @MaxZhang  I edited my answer to provide a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
mg = float(input('Please input the initial caffeine amount in mg: '))
mg /= 2
print(f'After 6 hours: {mg:.1f} mg caffeine left')
mg /= 2
print(f'After 12 hours: {mg:.1f} mg caffeine left')
mg /= 4
print(f'After 24 hours: {mg:.1f} mg caffeine left')
```

use `f-string`: `f"{value:format}"`

Comment: do f-strings count as positional replacements?

Comment: @alexpdev Answer is No? Why?

Comment: because that is what OP says he needs to incorporate into his code.

Comment: I never knew about a "F-string" before, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could add positional replacement using a `list` that stores `float` values `[10.0f, 5.0f, 2.5f]`, and as for conversion, the text is using a **PEP** format proposed to add a new `string` formatting *mechanism*: *Literal String Interpolation*. **PEP**, such formats will be referred to as `“f-strings”`, taken from the leading *character* used to denote such `string`, and is definedd as “*formatted strings*”.

Format specifiers may also contain evaluated expressions

```
>>> width = 10
>>> quantity = 4
>>> value = decimal.Decimal('12.34567')
>>> f'result: {value:{width}.{quantity}}'
'result:      12.35'
```

the above example it is just a simple demostration to format certain numeric values for diferents variables representing any *object* (Coffe, Persons, Time).

```py
import datetime

dt = '2022-04-27 12:00:00'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
mg = float(input('Please input the initial caffeine amount in mg: '))

for i in range(3):
    mg /= 2
    print('{1} {0:%d} {2} {0:%B} {3} {4}:{0:%M%p} {5}mg caffeine left'.format(dt, "day", "month", "hour", dt.hour*i, mg))
```

out:

```
day 27 month April hour 00:00PM 2.5mg caffeine left
day 27 month April hour 12:00PM 1.25mg caffeine left
day 27 month April hour 24:00PM 0.625mg caffeine left
```